# c reading and writing strings visual studio 2013

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2013, c-strings

Every time I run this it stops working when I enter the string.I use visual studio 2013.Here's my code:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   int main(void){
    char x[10];
    scanf("%s",x);
    printf("%s",x);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you enter? How does it fail (Is it the "your_program.exe has stopped working" popup or something else)? Do you see any warnings?

Comment: What have you tried, what does the debugger say, what do you expect to happen? How do you make sure "the string" (11 chars!) fits into the array, etc.? Please improve your question.

Comment: are you entering string more than 9 characters ?

Comment: i just want to try if i can print the string

Comment: no problem with size no errors it runs and when i enter a word it stops working the debugger said there's an error "Unhandled exception at 0xFEFEFEFE in Project14.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003)."

Comment: Does it *always* crash, or just for some specific input? What is the input that makes it crash? Have you tried running a debug-build in the debugger? Where does the debugger say the crash happens?

Comment: debugger didnt specify where crash happened .no it doesnt crash this is the first time. i entered "program". is the problem with the compiler?

Comment: Try `scanf("%9s" ,x);`. If that doesn't work, then you'll have to use `scanf_s("%9s" , x, sizeof(x));`. The problem should disappear when you use one of these. If it doesn't, something is wrong somewhere else. You'll have to give more details.

Comment: thank you, it worked when i tried "scanf_s("%9s" , x, sizeof(x));" why didnt it work before? i didnt understand this statement can you please explain.

Comment: @codex , Haven't you been getting a warning saying that `scanf` is not safe? VS has its own set of safe functions. `scanf_s` is one of them. You'll have to use the safe functions. If you don't pay attention to compiler warnings, the result may be unexpected.

Comment: it did and i changed it to scanf_s and it still didnt work. Now i changed the size of the array to 100 and entered a small sentence and it only printed the first word...no errors shown at all.

Comment: @codex "it only printed the first word", that is because `scanf("%s",x);` doesn't save white-space.  What does your documentation say `"%s"` should do?

Comment: @chux i didnt understand your question..

Comment: @codex  When you comment "i changed the size of the array to 100 and entered a small sentence and it only printed the first word ..no errors shown at all." sounds like you find that result unexpected.  It is the correct functionality.  Certainly you have access to documentation about `scanf()` and the specifier `"%s"`. What does your documentation say about this?

Answer (score 1):

What *probably* happens is that the `stdout` output buffer is not flushed. By default `stdout` is *line buffered* meaning the output written to `stdout` will not actually be output until there is a newline.

So the solution is simply to write a newline:

```
printf("%s\n",x);
```

Also note that you can't write input more than nine characters, or you will write beyond the bounds of the array `x` and have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The number nine comes from your array being ten `char` big, and strings in C needs an extra character to terminate the string, so the largest string you can put in `x` is ten minus one.

Comment: tried it didnt work i thing the problem is in the scanf

Comment: @codex Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *buffer = calloc(1024, sizeof(char)); // you could replace sizeof(char) with 1 if you wanted
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    unsigned lng = strlen(buffer);
    buffer = realloc(buffer, (lng + 1)); // note sizeof(char) == 1, so no need to add it
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    system("pause");
    free(buffer);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Suggest `char buffer = (char *)calloc(1024 * sizeof(char));` --> `char *buffer = calloc(1024, sizeof *buffer);`

Comment: Two nit picks with your code: don't cast the result of malloc/realloc in C and sizeof(char) is redundant.

Comment: @chux - I put sizeof(char) to make it easier for some to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you put more than 9 characters into `x` then your program will give undefined behavior. Suppose, you input `abcdefghi`, then actual content of x is follows:

```
x[0] = 'a'
x[1] = 'b'
x[2] = 'c'
x[3] = 'd'
x[4] = 'e'
x[5] = 'f'
x[6] = 'g'
x[7] = 'h'
x[8] = 'i'
x[9] = '\0'
```

`scanf()` of string will automatically put `'\0'` at the end. When you are printing using `%s`, your `printf()` method will print until it reaches `'\0'`. But if in the array there is no `'\0'` character, then it may crash or print garbage value form system dump, because the `printf()` will try to print beyond your array indexing.